Nushell script: redirect stdout and stderr to a variable
I am writing a nushell testing script for a cli, and want to only print stdout, stderr and nushell errors when a function fails. To do this, I have to redirect stdout and stderr to a variable from a closure. This was harder than I thought. My solution was to save the output to a file, and open the file again later, something that feels clumsy and is in theory slow as well.
def run_tests [functions, passed, total] -> int {
    mut passed = $passed

    for pair in ($functions | enumerate) {
        print $"test ($pair.index): running" --no-newline
        try { 
THIS --->   do $pair.item.func out+err> /tmp/test-output # FIXME: this is a workaround for redirecting output to a variable, using a file, which is slow
            print $"\rtest ($pair.index): success"
            $passed += 1
        } catch {
            print $"\rtest ($pair.index): failure"
            print (open /tmp/test-output)
            print $in
        }
    }
    return $passed
}

The $functions parameter is a table with a column$func. It contains closures with assertions, nushell commands that can fail and external commands that can fail.
stuff i tried

let result = do $pair.item.func: also prints output of $func which is not what I want
complete: only works on external commands
do $pair.item.func out+err> $result: gives empty output, is for file redirections only

sample input
This is an example of tests. log-timer is the binary for the cli I'm testing.
let functions = [
    [name, func];
    [start-stop-label, {
        log-timer start test
        log-timer stop
        log-timer get logs
        assert (log-timer get logs | str contains test)
        }
    ],
    [overwrite-options, {
        touch ~/log-1.csv
        log-timer config set --log-file-path log-1.csv --row-formatter v1-0
        let config = log-timer config get | from json
        assert ($config.log_file_path == ('~/log-1.csv' | path expand))
        assert ($config.row_formatter == V1_0)

        log-timer config set --row-formatter v2-0
        let config = log-timer config get | from json
        assert ($config.log_file_path == ('~/log-1.csv' | path expand))
        assert ($config.row_formatter == V2_0)

        touch ~/log-2.csv
        log-timer config set --log-file-path ~/log-2.csv
        let config = log-timer config get | from json
        assert ($config.log_file_path == ('~/log-2.csv' | path expand))
        assert ($config.row_formatter == V2_0)
    },],
    [set-default, {
        log-timer config set-default --confirm
        let current = log-timer config get | from json
        let default = log-timer config get-default | from json
        assert ($current == $default)
    }],
]

sample output
How I want output to look if start-stop-label fails:
test 1: failure
started activity 'test'
stopped activity 'test'
Error:   × Assertion failed.
   ╭─[entry #4:1:8]
 1 │ assert (log-timer get logs | str contains test)
   ·        ──┬──
   ·          ╰── It is not true.
   ╰────
test 2: success
test 2: running

As you can see, both stdout, nushell errors is printed after the test fails. (I also want stderr)

Please set up and include in the question a sample $functions table that contains such closures, ideally of all kinds (assertions, internal, and external commands) and with both outcomes (succeeding and failing), as well as your expected output from a solution to that same sample input.

@Ask Sødal You're saying it's not an external command but your own function? Why don't you write to a variable in your function then instead of to stdout?

I want the tests to be easy to write. I updated my question to include sample $functions. If I did what you're suggesting, I would have to write boilerplate code in every test.
How would you do this? If it's short, it may be ok.
